# Stop local node app through command line

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line, cmd

e.g. When I `npm start` in cmd to run my node app on localhost,

```
C:\...> npm start

> myApp@001 start C:\...
> node index.js

App listening at http://:::80
```

I'm given the above, and not the option to input any further. From here, the only way to stop the app, as far as I know, is by closing cmd. This is quite tedious, as I would have to reopen cmd and navigate back to my directory to work further with my app.

Is there some sort of command to abort the app?

Comment: Uh, ctrl-c doesn't work?

Comment: It does - That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can quit any process by killing it from the command line. Here is an example with node.

`killall -9 node`